# Logical AND in GitLab CI workflow tag

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to create a pipeline only when the commit message contains some information inside [ ]-brackets and the trigger source is a push event. To achieve this I wrote

```yaml
workflow:
    rules:
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[[^\[\]]*?\]\n/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'push'
        - when: never
```

But it seems to ignore the source part, because if I try to trigger a pipeline via API call, it goes through if the last commit contains `[ ]`. The API call is refused only if the commit message doesn't satisfy the regular expression, but as far as I'm concerned it should always be blocked.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`when: never` specifies when NOT create a pipeline. You just need to use `when: always`, but since this is the default, you don't need to specify it. Also, use quotes around the conditional statement. Try this:

```yaml
workflow:
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[[^\[\]]*?\]\n/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
```

See [workflow:rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrules) for more information.